# Azure Consumption API: What meter rates are used in Azure Usage Details list

Tags: azure, api, billing, rate, consumption

I'm using the usage details API to pull a subscription-based Usage details list, and I'm trying to determine what rate was used in each one of the list items. 
I used this call
`GET https://management.azure.com/{scope}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-01-01`

Here is the response format -

```
{
  "value": [
{
  "id": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/201702/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails/usageDetailsId1",
  "name": "usageDetailsId1",
  "type": "Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails",
  "tags": {
    "env": "newcrp",
    "dev": "tools"
  },
  "properties": {
    "billingPeriodId": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/billingPeriods/201702",
    "invoiceId": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/providers/Microsoft.Billing/invoices/201703-123456789",
    "usageStart": "2017-02-13T00:00:00Z",
    "usageEnd": "2017-02-13T23:59:59Z",
    "instanceName": "shared1",
    "instanceId": "/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/Default-Web-eastasia/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/shared1",
    "instanceLocation": "eastasia",
    "currency": "USD",
    "usageQuantity": 0.00328,
    "billableQuantity": 0.00328,
    "pretaxCost": 0.67,
    "isEstimated": false,
    "meterId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "partNumber": "Part Number 1",
    "resourceGuid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "offerId": "Offer Id 1",
    "chargesBilledSeparately": true,
    "location": "EU West"
  }
 }
 ]
}
```

Does anyone know if the rate can be calculated as follows:
meterRate = pretaxCost/usageQuantity?

Comment: Hi Tal Sofer, Just FYI we are trying to find information (around meterRate calculation) internally with concerned team. Will update this thread if we get any update. Thanks.